# Finding error in the following sentence

Tags: phrase-usage

I was given a question and I had to find error in it

> The priest class took upon itself the monopoly (1)/ of scriptural knowledge and interpretation (2)/ of the same to its own advantage. (3)/ No error (4)

Answer was **part 1**

I am not able to figure out the correct answer.

IS the error lies in the usage of **take upon itself**, **take upon itself is usually used as **take upon itself to do something** and hence in the sentence above it is used wrong.

Somebody help me understand this

Answer (score 1):

In the given sentence:

> The priest class took upon itself the monopoly of scriptural knowledge and interpretation  of the same to its own advantage.

I do not see a grammatical error. As a matter od **style** I might have written "claimed" or "held" rather than "took upon itself". I might have written "*scriptural knowledge and interpretation*" or "*scriptural knowledge and **it**s interpretation*"  instead of "*scriptural knowledge and interpretation  of the same*". But neither of thsoe would be correcting an error.